# In the context of the example provided, does dividing method into parts using synchronized(this) helps with performance?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, this

I'm new to Java concurrency and I saw an example online of trying to improve performance while maintaining concurrency by synchronise on part of a method.

Example:

```
public class TwoSums {

    private int sum1 = 0;
    private int sum2 = 0;

    public void add(int val1, int val2){
        synchronized(this){
            this.sum1 += val1;   
            this.sum2 += val2;
        }
    }
}
```

Improved example:

```
public class TwoSums {

    private int sum1 = 0;
    private int sum2 = 0;

    public void add(int val1, int val2){
        synchronized(this){
            this.sum1 += val1;   
        }
        synchronized(this){
            this.sum2 += val2;
        }
    }
}
```

The author of the article mentioned that:

> Now two threads can execute the add() method at the same time. One
>   thread inside the first synchronized block, and another thread inside
>   the second synchronized block. This way threads will have to wait less
>   for each other to execute the add() method.

My question is, for the improved example, even though the method is divided into two parts using `synchronised(this)`, we are still synchronising on the SAME "this" object, so even though two different thread can access the method `add` at the same time, we still CAN'T update the value of `sum1` and `sum2` at the same time, right? But the author said we CAN.

I am very confused by it.

Comment: The author is wrong.

Comment: You are right. The author is wrong.  I am assuming that this is some very very simple explanatory code as it would make no sense to do this in real life

Comment: The author isn't wrong in terms of the words he has used, but a micro-optimization like this is likely to have little benefit, or even negative benefit, because of the costs incurred by the `synchronized` keywords. If the content of each block was large in relation to that, there would be an improvement in concurrency. Whether that would be semantically correct is another thing, and whether such a design has any point in the first place is yet another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm. I don't think the second version will be faster. Because in the second version, the first thread acquires the monitor (`this`) at line -1 and then even if the second thread arrives, **it will have to wait for the first thread to release the lock / monitor**, (and cannot proceed).

Additionally, 2 synchornized blocks means additional Memory barrier instructions emitted by the JVM, which means additional flushing of memory. The second one should actually be slower.

Answer (score 1):

> for the improved example, even though the method is divided into two parts using syncrhonized(this), we are still synchronizing on the SAME "this" object, so even though two different thread can access the method add at the same time, we still CAN'T update the value of sum1 and sum2 at the same time, right?

You are correct.  If the threads are both synchronizing on the same object instance then only one can be within a `synchronized` block at a time.

> But the author said we CAN.

This author is mistaken.  I've seen the original page and I've asked him to fix it because it's obviously in error.

To provide some more details, it's important to realize is that some sort of memory synchronization is necessary if multiple threads are updating the `sum1` and `sum2` fields.  A faster and safe alternative would be to use `AtomicInteger`s instead:

```
private final AtomicInteger sum1 = new AtomicInteger();
private final AtomicInteger sum2 = new AtomicInteger();
...
public void add(int val1, int val2) {
    // no manual synchronization needed
    sum1.addAndGet(val1);
    sum2.addAndGet(val2);
}
```